# Let $p(z)$ be a polynomial: prove $\frac{p'(z)}{p(z)}=...$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Let $p(z)$ be a polynomial of degree $n \ge 1$ , and $z_1, z_2,...,z_n$ its roots (each repeated as often as its multiplicity). Show that

a) $$\frac{p'(z)}{p(z)}= \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{z-z_k} (z \neq z_k, k=1,2,...,n)$$

I am not sure how to start this part. I started with the general definition of a polynomial then tried the differentiation but I cannot reach the conclusion.

b) all the roots of the polynomial $p'(z)$ are in the convex hull spanned by the roots of $p(z)$; that is, in the smallest convex set containing the roots $z_1, z_2,...,z_n$ of $p(z)$.

Do I need part a to complete this part? I know the definition of a convex hull space but I am not seeing the connection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(a) The [logarithmic derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_derivative)
$$
L(f) = \frac{f'}{f}
$$
satisfies
$$
L(fg) = L(f) + L(g)
$$

Apply this to $p(z)=\prod_{k=1}^n (z-z_k)$, noting that $L(z-z_k) = \dfrac{1}{z-z_k}$.

(b) is the [Gauss–Lucas theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Lucas_theorem) and can indeed be proved using (a).