How to prove that $\frac{p'(x)}{p(x)} = \sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{1}{x-r_i}$ for all complex roots of $r_i$ of $p(x)$?

How to prove that $\frac{p'(x)}{p(x)} = \sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{1}{x-r_i}$ for all complex roots of $r_i$ of $p(x)$?


For real roots, it can be easily proven with product rule, but for complex roots, I cant apply product rule, so I tried induction which did not work either, how to prove this then?

actually, the product rule is still true over the complex numbers! so you're good to go.

@hunter do we need complex analysis for that, or can we just prove with real analysis only? My course hasn't yet covered complex analysis so it would be nice to know if there's one such proof

Downvoter please elaborate

The definition of derivative of a polynomial (with coefficients in any commutative ring) is purely algebraic: if $P(X)=\sum_{k=0}^na_kX^k$ then $P'(X)=\sum_{k=1}^nka_kX^{k-1}$, and satisfies $(AB)'=A'B+AB'$ (the heart of the proof is to check it when $A,B$ are monomials).

Possible duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1659918/let-pz-be-a-polynomial-prove-fracpzpz

Followup of my previous comment: both sides of $\frac{p'(x)}{p(x)} = \sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{1}{x-r_i}$ shouldn't be considered as (meromorphic) complex functions, but  as elements of the field $\Bbb C(x)$, which is a purely algebraic object, defined as the field of fractions of the (differential) ring $\Bbb C[x]$.

put differently the algebraic claim to be proven is $p(x) := \prod_{k=1}^n (x-r_k)\implies p'(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n \prod_{j\neq k}(x-r_j)$ and proving it over $\mathbb R[x]$ actually implies the result over $\mathbb F[x]$ by principle of permanence of identities.  If OP does not know enough algebra to make sense of this then more background is needed -- i.e. as is the original post is lacking context.

Here is an argument that the product-rule is valid which doesn't appeal to complex analysis, although it does need the fundamental theorem of algebra.
If $p(x)$ is a real polynomial, then any complex roots come in conjugate pairs. So we just need to show the product rule holds formally for polynomials of the form $(x - \alpha)(x-\overline{\alpha})$. But such a polynomial is of the form $x^2 - \frac{\alpha + \overline{\alpha}}{2} + \overline{\alpha}\alpha$. All coefficients are real, so the derivative of this makes sense without knowing any complex analysis, and is $2x - (\alpha + \overline{\alpha})$. But this is exactly what you would get by applying the product rule formally to the factorization.
